# How to embed compilable python code onto Confluence

Tags: python, ping, confluence

I have written a python code to ping a list of ip addresses and return whether the host is up or down.

However, I am not sure how can I embed this python code onto Confluence (Atlassian) and be able to refresh this python code every minute.

The code snippet that I have is something as below:

```
import os,subprocess

hostip=['10.100.102.34', '10.100.102.40']

for i in hostip:
    pingit = "ping -n 1"+ i + "|grep TTL"
    process = subprocess.Popen(pingit, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    process.wait()

    if pingit!=0
       return 'hostname is up'
    elif
       return 'hostname is down'
```

Comment: Two quick possibilities come to mind. Number one, make an html page which you store wherever, and then use an html-include on a confluence page to display the html page. Number two, use javascript instead of python, include it inline on a confluence page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Apache to front Confluence, I would recommend creating a vhost that runs on a different port like 5555. Then have your Python Script (And anything else for the future) run out of this Apache Vhost.

Then you can use the `{html-include}` functionality to include this new local directory.